# Caching: Set expiration date for images

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

In order to improve the loading speed of my webpage I want to set an expiration date for the images. 
I am not sure though how to do this.

I am loading my image through CSS, through Cloudfront from an S3 bucket in AWS. Where do I specify the expiration date?

This is an example of how I load my pics:

```
.bg-header {
  background: url("https://dt25rte355.cloudfront.net/assets/12456.jpg"); 
  background-size: cover;
  height:480px;
```

Comment: Why expire the cache? The images will still be there but will load even more slowly.

Comment: @EternalHour - Expiration is done so that if the image changes, the old image won't be cached forever and the browser will get the new image.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson -- I can understand that, but I don't understand using this as a means to boost performance.

Comment: The `max-age` directive tells the browser how long it can cache the resource.  Without it (or the expires header) the browser doesn't know for how long the resource is valid and may not cache it at all.

Comment: Cloudfront should automatically do this for you. If you want higher or lower expiry date, you can set custom tags on assets by accessing asset's meta-data in S3. Also, you can set custom TTL on Cloudfront distribution. Also, check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html There are several cache control headers. Some for CDN (Cloudfront) and some for browser.

Comment: What tool are you using to upload your content to S3?

Comment: Thanks Rakesh Bollampally, I set it through AWS and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the directory containing your files, create a new file called `.htaccess` and add the following inside:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800"
</FilesMatch>
```

You can add additional file types to the regular expression, and apache will add the specified header to every image request. Note this method will require your files to be hosted on a server.

Comment: The original question specifically indicates that the server is S3, which does not use `.htaccess`, behind CloudFront, which doesn't use it either.  This answer, while presumably helpful in other scenarios, is an incorrect answer to this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

To add a Cache-Control or Expires header field to Amazon S3 objects using the Amazon S3 console

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3.
2. In the Amazon S3 console, in the Bucket name list, choose the name of the bucket that contains the files.
3. In the Name list, choose the name of the object that you want to add a header to.
4. Choose Properties, and then choose Metadata.
5. Choose Add Metadata, and then in the Key menu, choose Cache-Control or Expires.
6. In the Value field, type one of the following:
   · For a Cache-Control field, type:
   max-age=number of seconds that you want objects to stay in a CloudFront edge cache
   · For an Expires field, type a date and time in HTML format.
7. Choose Save.